# fix Windows 7 corrupted user profile, without destroying settings?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I have read countless answers about corrupted user profiles, which all suggest re-creating a new profile and copying user files. I am looking for an **alternative** solution.

I have a Windows 7 Home Premium, non-networked, and my user profile is corrupted, I think. When logging on, I click on my picture, and the after the welcome screen, I get a blank screen with a mouse pointer. I tried waiting, but no desktop appeared after 24 hours.  I created another user profile "Sanjay2" and copied my `C:\Users\Sanjay` files into `C:\Users\Sanjay2`. The new profile loads fine.

I need to revive my old profile. I have looked in

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S...
```

and I have tried resetting `RefCount` back to `0` (it was `1`), `State` back to `0`, `Flags` is `0` too. Not sure what else can be done.

The reason I don't want to start form a new profile is that I have a huge number of custom settings in the old profile -- which are all lost in the new profile. These appear to be app-specific settings that are stored in `user.dat`. This includes favourites, MRUs, carefully positioned column setups in tables, Explorer window positions, game graphics settings, autobackup configurations, custom settings for 4 IDEs, many photoshop plugin settings etc etc.

Ideally I want to find the offending portions in the "corrupted" profile and remove them. Is there any way to find out what is causing it? My suspicion is that it might be a mapped drive or something? (I have a USB wifi dongle which is does not connect to internet untile some time after logon). Could that be it? If so can I trace such things?

I suppose one final last-ditch option is to export the `HKUsers` into the new profile, one branch at a time, from the old profile... And of course run the risk of the problem occurring again. Anyone had any experience of this, or offer any further tips?

Comment: When you get the blank (black?) screen, does Ctrl+Alt+Del work?

Comment: Do you have any backup system in place? You could try restoring an older copy of your ntuser.dat.  (If you don't have backups, it is time to start!)

Comment: @and31415 Ctrl+Alt+Del does nothing. Have to power off by holding the power button for 5 seconds!

Comment: @Zoredache I use an archiving system and have backups of all my files, but not of `ntuser.dat` unfortunately.... I think you are right that I should also back up `ntuser.dat`, although I think it's more tricky because I don't think it's possible to copy that file while logged in to the same profile.

Comment: Windows Backup has in-built "image" backups that will backup the entire system image, aim to use that going forward. :)